# How would I generate 1000 2x2 matrices whose elements are random numbers?

Tags: r, matrix, calculus

How would I do this in R? The prompt is:

Generate 1000 2⇥2 matrices whose elements are random numbers(not all integers) that range between 10 and 10.2.For each matrix compute the eigenvalues.
Plot each eigenvalue

So far I've done 
M=matrix(runif(4, min=-10, max=10), ncol=2, nrow=-10)

and I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: this looks like homework.  Homework is allowed on SO, but you should explain what you've tried to do so far and where you got stuck -- don't just cut-and-paste a homework assignment please ...

Comment: My bad, sorry about that. But what I first tried doing was M=matrix(runif(4), ncol=2, nrow=2) but I didn't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want this as a list, but if you do:

```
mats <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) matrix(runif(4), ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
eigens <- lapply(mats, eigen)
```

Comment: thank you so much! this was really helpful. Do you know how to have a specific matrix show up by #?

Comment: @TiffanyNguyen mats[[1000]] or change value to whatever matrix you want to see

Comment: @TiffanyNguyen it is actually suppose to be eigens[10] or whatever number you want

Comment: @TiffanyNguyen Did my code work for you? If so could you checkmark it so I know it's closed